# Insert db array to laravel

Tags: html, database, laravel

I've read a lot of laravel tutorial to do this but none has worked for me.

This is my form

```html
<div class="row increment  control-group">
  {{-- Request Item --}}
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="request_item[]" placeholder="Item" />
  </div>
  {{-- Request Description --}}
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="request_description[]" placeholder="Item Description" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn-item" type="button">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my controller

```html
$request->validate([
            'request_no' => 'required|max:255',
   'request_date' => 'required|date', //unique:(tablename)
            'request_item' => 'required|max:255',
            'request_description' => 'max:255',
            'request_by' => 'required|max:255',
            'request_status' => 'required|max:255',
            'request_scan' => 'mimes:pdf',
            'created_by' => 'max:255',
            'updated_by' => 'max:255',
  ]);
        
        //For file uploading
  $name="";
  if($request->hasfile('filename')){
   $file = $request->file('filename');
   $name = time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();
   $file->move(public_path(). '/images/', $name);
  }
        
        $itemArray = Input::get('request_item');
        $count = count($itemArray);

        
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
            $request= new \Trisco\IT_Request;
            $request->request_no=$request->get('request_no');
            $request->request_date=$request->get('request_date');
            $request->request_item=$itemArray[$i];
            $request->reqeust_description='';
            $request->request_by=$request->get('request_by');
            $request->request_status=$request->get('request_status');
            $passport->request_scan = $name; //file
            $request->added_by=$request->get('username');
            $request->updated_by=$request->get('username');
            $request->save();
        }
```

The request_item & request_description are both string only.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

how about you loop on your array?

```
$itemArray = Input::get('request_item');
foreach ($itemArray as $value) {
  $request->request_item=$value;
  //your code here
  //request->save()
}
```

Comment: Hi Francis! It's still the same error.

public function columnize(array $columns)
    {
        return implode(', ', array_map([$this, 'wrap'], $columns));
    }

Answer (score 0):

What is the error?
check also the spelling --

```
$request->reqeust_description='';
```

try this >>

```
$request->request_item= implode(',', $request['request_item']);
```

Comment: "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given"

I've fixed the spelling but still the same error